# Loop over all files on FTP using batch command

Tags: for-loop, ftp, batch-file, connection

Hi I want to LOOP through files on FTP and copy one by one. Every thing is fine with FTP connection and accessing folders. 
My question is How can loop through all files on FTP. It looks like there is no "For" type of functionality available to access FTP files because each line is considered as complete command.

```
open MyServerName 21 
MyUserName
MyPassword
lcd E:\LocalDirectory
cd /FTPDirectory/upload
I WANT TO LOOP THROGH ALL FILES AND COPY ONE BY ONE TO LOCAL DIRECTORY
disconnect
bye
```

Why i want to loop through all files in FTP is, I want to copy only those files which are not locked and available for copy.

Comment: and you are using MS Windows' `cmd`, I assume?

Comment: you can automate these type of sessions using, for example, `expect`; but that is only available, AFAIK, under unix-like operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different FTP client: wget.

With the `-m` option (for --mirror), use the following in a script

```
cd mylocaldirectory
wget -m ftp://username:password@hostname/theremotedirectory
```

Comment: I am working in windows environment... is wget available here ?